# What soundcard do I need to reduce latency and how does ASIO work?

Tags: ableton-live, homerecording

I work with Ableton Live 10 and I have a latency issue, i think it is because I only have a internal soundcard.

Voice and guitar run into the PC via a Macky Mixer ProFX 16x2.
I also use a Avid Eleven Rack, the Rack wants a ASIO driver and Ableton seems to be doing better with it. (latency)
But if i use ASIO nothing else works on my PC.

What Soundcard should I get for homerecording if i want to use ASIO, reduce the latency and hear other stuff while using ASIO?

I don't have much knowledge of soundcards.
I don't care if it is a internal or external soundcard.

I don't know if it is relevant but here are some other components I use:
Microkorg
Novation Bassstation 2
Roland GR-20
Roland V Drum

Comment: You can potentially have multiple sound cards, one supporting the ASIO software and the other for everything else.  Some sound cards (even internal) have front and back panel connections which can be set to act independently.  Others (like mine) not only have that feature but a SPDIF output as well, giving me three ways of sending audio out of my system.

Answer (score 2):

I know Propellerhead Reason does have a setting to allow other applications to use audio as well. I don't know about Ableton Live, but I found this: [Disabling exclusive mode for ASIO interfaces](https://help.ableton.com/hc/en-us/articles/209770485-Disabling-exclusive-mode-for-ASIO-interfaces)

Then if you want to buy a card it's hard to give advice on that other than the many articles will tell you when you Google it. I think EMU 0404 USB is a pretty OK soundcard, but there are quite a few good brands out there, all with their pros and cons. 
What matters is of course your budget, but also how many devices you want to record simultaneously, do you want to be able to expand with a breakout box later, do you need MIDI, etc.